# Identifying the column of the source data in a pivot table using VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

This should be very simple, but it is hard for me. I have a Pivot Table. I just want to know, using VBA, which column of the original data was used to totalize the pivot table. I need the column letter or number of such data field.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you put your mouse in a cell of the pivot table and use the ribbon menu to go to 'Pivot Table Analyse' you can click on 'Field List' or 'Change Data Source' to find out how to pivot table is built up

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is the code to locate that column. The idea is to determine if the source column is one or another of the multiple numeric columns in the original tables. Any ideas?

Comment: Temporarily, I have been using this code, but I think it is a poor man's solution:
 
pt is my PivotTable
 
If InStr(pt.DataFields(1), Cells(1, myNumericColumn).text) > 0 Then
etc...

Need a professional solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`SourceName` is the property you want I think

```vb
Dim pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

For Each pf In pt.DataFields
    Debug.Print pf.Name, pf.SourceName
Next pf
```